# Outputting links in PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
$info_str = "";
if ($DisplayURL == 1)
{

    $url = rtrim($url);
    if ($TruncateShowURL > 0)
    {
        if (strlen($url) > $TruncateShowURL)
            $url = substr($url, 0, $TruncateShowURL) . "...";
    }
    $info_str .= $url;
}
```

The URLs are shown as text, how can I convert them to clickable ones?
Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like you output anything at all in this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687662/how-can-i-convert-a-text-url-into-a-clickable-link-in-a-php-page

Comment: @Marty, it is a part of a search script where urls should be shown under the context.

Comment: @showdev, I read that post, but I couldn't find the proper solution matching my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code below to suit your environment

```
if ($DisplayURL == 1){
   $info_str .= "<a href='".$url."'>".$url."</a>";

}
```

Comment: That worked well, but I had to do the following:

$info_str .= "<a href=.$url.>$url</a>";

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @supersonictt In that case you should do this `echo "<a href=\"$url\">$url</a>";`, having the quotes is good for html I believe.

Comment: @lemondrop Quotes are in best practice for HTML, but you do not need to escape using slashes. See my update

Comment: @lemondrop thank you so much for the info, I implemented your suggestion.

Comment: @DarylGill I escaped the slashes because using "" for un-parsed strings is a bit redundant because they are slower than '' strings. Using this I just put the vars right inside the string and the quotes are inserted without the string adding and all that.

Comment: @DarylGill thank you for the info. I am still practising PHP, that's why I came here for help. Thanks all for helping me.